# How to backup partition tables during Linux installation, preferably working for Ubuntu or Kubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

During a recent update to 13.10 from 13.04, Ubuntu crashed and became unstable. My attempts to repair it led to no results and I have finally decided to reinstall it, replacing in the process the unity-gnome graphical interface by the KDE.

However, provided that the machine I am going to reinstall the linux on has a dual-boot with Windows 8 and a UEFI that might lead to the complication during the installation of a different OS in a dual-boot, I wanted to back up my partition tables.

While installing the Ubuntu 13.04 I have used for this purpose the Ubuntu secure remix (currently renamed to linux-secure), which includes a tool to automatically back-up and restore partition tables during the installation from a liveUSB.

However, I wasn't able to find a 13.10 Ubuntu or Kubuntu version that includes that tool.

Thus right now I am looking for a method allowing me to back up my partition tables before Linux installation in dual-boot with a different OS, preferably available for Ubuntu or Kubuntu.

Comment: @Chenmunka: Thanks for your comment, I tried edited my question to better fit the requirements.

Comment: @Bobby: Could you please de-hold the answer now that it has been modified to fit the stackexchange quality standards?